# Unable to send text messages after restoring iPhone

Tags: iphone, messages, restore

I restored my new iPhone using a third party app iSkysoft. It uses iTunes backup and restored my phone. I used it as needed to selectively restore my phone due to storage problem. Now, after restoring I am facing this problem that for all the Messages conversations that I restored, I am unable to send them message. I checked the phone number, which appears to be fine, but message cannot be cannot send.

How do I resolve this issue?

Comment: Did you work through https://support.apple.com/en-ca/HT204065 yet?

Comment: I did. Before the restore, I sent messages to 2 persons. After restore, im only able to send message to these persons and 2-3 more and none else. I am talking about sms not the imessage.

Answer (score 1):

Try disabling iMessage and then enabling it again (from Settings => Messages => iMessage).

Comment: I did, its still same.